# Cursor jumps when crossing boundary between multiple monitors - it works fine near the top of the screen but gets progressively worse near the bottom

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, mouse-cursor

I just got a new monitor and am experiencing a strange issue - the cursor will jump a different amount of pixels when switching monitors, depending on the height of the cursor. Like this:

[image: 1]

There's a specific pixel height near the top where it crosses perfectly, but the gap gets wider the further from this height the cursor gets. That includes going above this height.

Rearranging the display settings is obviously no good - I can get the wallpapers to match up just fine, the problem is the cursor.

Answer (score 2):

That's simply a question of geometry and resolution. Example:

[image: Screens]

For the sake of simplicity the resolution of both monitors is 100x300. Viewing the image as it is the green line appears clearly shorter than the purple one, but in pixel count they are both exactly 100px long.

In this case the difference is caused by the screen geometry. Difference in resolution has similar effect.